# How can you set anisotropy filtering value on A-Frame textures?

Tags: three.js, aframe

I am working on an A-Frame project that has small textures in the distance that are hard to see with the default three.js texture anisotropy setting of 1. How can you set this value on a texture in an A-Frame project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a revised component incorporating the suggested event listener and maximum anisotropy value.

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('max-anisotropy', {
  dependencies: ['material', 'geometry'],
  init: function () {
    // wait until this material is ready ...
    this.el.addEventListener('materialtextureloaded', () => {
      let myMap = this.el.getObject3D('mesh').material.map;
      myMap.anisotropy = this.el.sceneEl.renderer.capabilities.getMaxAnisotropy();
      myMap.needsUpdate = true;
    })
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very simple A-Frame component that I created to solve this problem:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('af', {
  dependencies: ['material', 'geometry'],
  init: function () {
    // wait until this material is ready ...
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.el.getObject3D('mesh').material.map.anisotropy = 4;
      this.el.getObject3D('mesh').material.map.needsUpdate = true;
    }, 5000);
  },
})
```

I cheat here by using `setTimeout` as I see an error without adding a delay to implementing the anisotropy setting change.

UPDATE: It might be possible to listen for the "materialtextureloaded" event per this example from the A-Frame docs: https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/components/visible.html#hiding-entity-until-texture-loaded

Comment: Instead of assigning a hard-coded value for anisotropy, you might want to do this: `map.anisotropy = renderer.capabilities.getMaxAnisotropy();`. In this way, you can retrieve the max anisotropy value which depends on the user's device.